# spaCy, NER, documentation about the different label types of a particular LM

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am using spaCy for named entity recognition (NER). According to [the spaCy docs](https://spacy.io/models/en), the language model `en_core_web_sm` is able to recognize 18 different entity types, i. e., it provides 18 labels such as `DATE`, `PERSON` or `ORG`.

I am particularly interested in the labels `LOC` (location), `FAC` (facilities) and `GPE` (gepolitical entities). Is there documentation about which objects are typically labelled with those labels? Have the guidelines used for labelling the entities been published?

I am asking, because sometimes it is not clear to me why a particular object is labelled as say `FAC` and not as `GPE`, or why an object is not labelled at all. Let's have a look at an example:

```
#spacy.cli.download('en_core_web_sm')
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
text = 'Alice Miller went to the Empire State Building. Next she went to Times Square. Finally she went to the train station.'
doc = nlp_en(text)
displacy.render(doc, style='ent')
```

The output is:

[image]

To my mind, the Empire State Building is correctly labelled as `GPE`. The Times Square, however, is labelled as `FAC`; I expected `GPE`. And "train station" is not recognized at all; I expected `FAC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the page for a pipeline you'll see the data sources listed. For the NER data in the English pipelines OntoNotes is used. The schema is documented in the [OntoNotes Manual](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/docs/LDC2013T19/OntoNotes-Release-5.0.pdf), for example:

```
PERSON People, including fictional
NORP Nationalities or religious or political groups
FACILITY Buildings, airports, highways, bridges, etc.
ORGANIZATION Companies, agencies, institutions, etc.
GPE Countries, cities, states
LOCATION Non-GPE locations, mountain ranges, bodies of water
PRODUCT Vehicles, weapons, foods, etc. (Not services)
EVENT Named hurricanes, battles, wars, sports events, etc.
WORK OF ART Titles of books, songs, etc.
LAW Named documents made into laws 
LANGUAGE Any named language
```

In spacy you can get these definitions using [`spacy.explain`](https://spacy.io/api/top-level/#spacy.explain), like `spacy.explain("FACILITY")`. Sometimes the official documentation has more detailed explanations, though in this case it seems not to.

"train station" is not picked up because it is not a named entity - named entities are typically proper nouns, not common nouns.

Also note the model is not perfect and it will make mistakes, and it is hard to explain individual mistakes (see [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3052)).